# How to literally add newline character in vscode cpp snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

How can I add the following line to the body of my vs code CPP snippet?

```
#define edl '\n'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I think you could improve your chances of getting an answer if you review the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and modify your question.

Comment: To clarify, as @HelloChen had in his snippet, use '`\\n'` to insert a literal `'\n'` into your output.  So `"#define edl '\\n'",`

Answer (score 1):

```
"Print to #include <stdio.h>":{
        "scope": "c,cpp",
        "prefix": "std",
        "body": [
        "/* Hello Chen C program */",
        "#include <stdio.h>",
        "#include <stdlib.h>\n",
        "int main(void)",
        "{",
        "    ${1:printf(\"${2:Hello Chen\\n}\");}",
        "    ${3:system(\"pause\");}",
        "}",
        ],
        "description": "stdio.h"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

**I can clearly understand your problem , just copy and paste and don't forget to rate and vote**

{
// Place your snippets for c here. Each snippet is defined under a snippet name and has a prefix, body and
// description. The prefix is what is used to trigger the snippet and the body will be expanded and inserted. Possible variables are:
// $1, $2 for tab stops, $0 for the final cursor position, and ${1:label}, ${2:another} for placeholders. Placeholders with the
// same ids are connected.
// Example:
"Print to console": {
"prefix": "jeetC",
"body": [

```
        "#include <stdio.h>",
        "#include <conio.h>",
        "#include <math.h>",
        "#include <string.h>",
        "#include <stdlib.h>",
        
        "\n",
        "int main()",
        "{   $2 ",
        "   printf(\"\\n\");",
        "   printf(\"\\n\");",
        "return 0;",
    "}",

    ],
    "description": "Log output to console"
}
```

}